# Trying to find date of 2010 for all records in a list (version 4.0)

Tags: .net

I'm going through a list and trying to find only the records that have 2010 as their year and displaying the the record using this code:

```
var dateSorted =
from e in deserializedRoster
where DateTime.Equals = "2010"
select e;
foreach (var e in dateSorted) Console.WriteLine("Date 2010: {0}", e.ToString());
Console.WriteLine();
```

The line DateTime.Equals needs work. I don't know how to instruct the code to look only for 2010 in the year. The field is called "date".

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly and `date` is a `DateTime`, you'll want to check if the `Year` property of `e.date` is 2010.

```
var dateSorted =
from e in deserializedRoster
where e.date.Year == 2010
select e;
```